# In mutual induction driven by a sine wave, is the waveform in the secondary coil also a sine wave?

Tags: electromagnetism, electromagnetic-induction

What will be the waveform in the secondary coil of the transformer if the input is a sine wave of some frequency and constant voltage. Will there be any change in the waveform or will it remain same?

Answer (score 1):

There will be no change in the waveform $-$ if the driver is a pure sine wave, then the response on the secondary will also be a pure sine wave at an identical frequency. This is a general property of [linear time-invariant systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_time-invariant_system).

Comment: can you please provide the mathematical verification

Comment: See [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/469700) and [this](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/368181) threads, and the links therein, particularly [this one](https://ptolemy.berkeley.edu/eecs20/week9/lti.html).

Comment: Definitely _not_ a pure sine wave: in any real case with a transformer with a ferromagnetic core, the secondary waveform will be distorted, and this distortion can be quite high in certain conditions.

Comment: @MassimoOrtolano Indeed, real-world examples can break both linearity and time-invariance depending on conditions. OP's focus is on mutual induction, which does not include any hysteresis or saturation effects from a ferromagnetic core.

Comment: See if the input pulse is positive half cycle of sine wave then will the output be positive half or will it become negative